# Let $x\in\mathbb R^d$ such that $||x||_2=1$. How to prove that the expected absolute value of a random walk on $x$ is at least $1/\sqrt 2$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, expected-value, random-walk, upper-lower-bounds

Let $x\in\mathbb R^d$ such that $||x||_2=1$, and let $Y_1,\ldots,Y_d$ be i.i.d. random variables such that $Y_i=\begin{cases}1&\mbox{w.p. 1/2}\\-1&\mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Define $Z=\sum_{i=1}^d x_i\cdot Y_i$.

> **How can we show that $$\mathbb E[|Z|]\ge 1/\sqrt 2$$ for any such vector $x$**?

---

Notice that we have $\mathbb E[|Z|]= 1/\sqrt 2$ for the vector $x=(1/\sqrt 2, 1/\sqrt 2,0,\ldots,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

This follows from [Khintchine inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khintchine_inequality?fbclid=IwAR2Kzq-5t33an10VZVqu-L1Gt0svuseolnrvT78gDxCgPMtZ87dbpiX7Yw4).